# delta live tables dump final gold table to cassandra

Tags: databricks, delta-live-tables

we have a delta live tables which read from kafka topic, clean/filter/process/aggregate the message, and dump it to bronze/silver/gold table, in order to build a REST service to retrieve the aggregated result, we need to dump the data from gold table to cassandra table. I tried to update the script for gold table, after the aggregated result to dump to gold, i added one more step to further dump the updated result to cassandra table but it didn't work:

```
@dlt.table
def test_live_gold():
  return (
    dlt.read("test_kafka_silver").groupBy("user_id", "event_type").count()

#     df = spark.read.format("delta")
#       .table("customer.test_live_gold")
#       .withColumnRenamed("user_id", "account_id")
#       .withColumnRenamed("event_type", "event_name")
#       .withColumn("last_updated_dt", current_timestamp())
#     df.show(5, False)
#     write_to_cassandra_table('customer', 'test_keyspace', df)
  )
```

how can I copy result from delta table to cassandra in one workflow as the delta live tables?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By default, Delta Live Tables only store data as Delta. If you need to write data to somewhere else, then you need to add another step in your job (Databricks workflow) that will use notebook to read data from gold table produced by the `test_live_gold` and write into Cassandra.  Something like this:

[image]

Comment: is it possible to read Gold tables data from SQL workspace?

Comment: yes, of course - you just connect to the tables in the `target` database you specified in settings

Comment: Thanks for the reply and is there any documentation for that? am looking to mount BigQuery Table and can ```Autoloader``` will load data to Silver tables?

Comment: It’s better to ask this as a separate question - I’m not sure I completely understand the question

Comment: Thanks for the comment and am not able to post new question. My intestion is to build a medallion architecture but my source data was in google BigQuery. So am checking for possibilities if mounting BigQuery table to databricks and will autoloader will capture the data or not so that will proceed to create further pipeline. @Alex Ott